Proving the GCD of Two Specific Polynomials is $(x-1)^3$
For any positive integer $ m $, the polynomials are defined as follows $(m>1)$:
$$f_m(x) = x^{2m+1} - (2m+1)x^{m+1} + (2m+1)x^m - 1$$
My goal is to prove that for any two distinct integers $ n $ and $ m $, the polynomials $ f_n(x) $ and $ f_m(x) $ have a gcd given by:
$$
\gcd(f_n(x), f_m(x)) = (x-1)^3
$$
In other words, I want to determine if they do not have any common complex roots other than 1.
What I've tried:
I have been using the Euclidean algorithm to compute the gcd for some small cases with computer. However, I haven't been able to detect any clear patterns in their coefficients when using Bézout's identity to express the gcd.
So I am seeking for a theoretical proof.
Thanks for your time!

How to ask a good question. In particular, please add what you have tried.

By the duplicate, $f_m=g_m(x-1)^3$, where $g_m$ is irreducible of degree $2(m-1)$. This yields your claim.

Hmmm the linked duplicate hasn't received an answer covering all cases, right?

Yes, you are right. The duplicate question is still open in some cases. One could try to find a complete solution and add it there. I think it is possible to find something in the literature, but I didn't search for it yet.

@DietrichBurde Could you kindly assist in finding a complete solution in the literature? Any guidance or references on how to fully resolve this would be appreciated. Thank you in advance for your time and help!

Did you search already this site? Since derivatives of arithmetic progressions are irreducible, see here, you could do it one more time to divide by $(x-1)^3$, see the comment by The SimplyFire.

@DietrichBurde Thank you! However, I’m still struggling to see how this relates to my case,
for example $f_3(x) = (x^6 + x^5 + x^4 - 6x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)(x-1) = (x^5 + 2x^4 + 3x^3 - 3x^2 - 2x - 1)(x-1)^2 = (x^4 + 3x^3 + 6x^2 + 3x + 1)(x-1)^3$ , which intuitively feels different from the derivatives of arithmetic progressions.
Could you clarify the connection between these two types of polynomials?
